# Merge a Date object which has 04:00 as its time with another time string ("8:30am") into a new Date object

Tags: mongodb, date

I have a mongo db with a document that has a date and a time separately.

Date object was intended to be just a date, so it has the time as 
04:00 (time-zone adjusted to -4)

```
db.logs.findOne().date
```

> ISODate("2014-08-05T04:00:00Z")

And there's a separate time field which is still a string

```
db.logs.findOne().time
```

> 8:30am

How do I merge them both into one field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.logs.find().forEach(function(log) {
    log.date = new Date(log.date.getFullYear(),
            /* date */  log.date.getMonth(), 
                        log.date.getDate(), 
            /* time */  parseInt(log.time)
            /* + 12 if PM */ + (((log.time.charAt(log.time.length - 2) + log.time.charAt(log.time.length - 1)) === 'pm') ? 12 : 0));
    db.logs.save(log);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the combination client-side, using appropriate libraries to handle calendar and clock calculations, and then update/insert the document. MongoDB (as of 2.6, anyway) doesn't have facilities for updating to the combination server side.